# Javascript + Codeigniter - Display only the outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the result of a query, and what I want is the exact data (Latitude and Longitudes). The queries seems to be working, because I get outputs, but it's in this form :

```
[{"latitude":"8.50661","longitude":"124.635"}]
```

What I want is in this format :

```
[8.50661,124.635]
```

Here's my code btw:

Controller:

```
public function retAddress()
{
    $cid = $this->input->post('input_cesid');
    $convAddress = $this->agent_model->getAddress($cid);
    echo json_encode($convAddress);

}
```

Model :

```
public function getAddress($data)
{
    $condition = "(SELECT work_address FROM test_workers WHERE work_cesid='". $data . "')";
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM geocoding WHERE address=". $condition);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Ajax:

```
$('#searchMark').submit(function (event) {
    dataString = $("#input_cesid").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Functions/retAddress",
        data:dataString,
        success:function (data) {
            $('#testingOutput').html(data);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build result in backend

```
echo '['.$query->result()['latitude'].','.$query->result()['longitude'].']';
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped!

Answer (score 0):

just like this 
if you have multiple result then you can use forloop instead $result[0]['latitude']*

```
 public function getAddress($data){

    $condition = "(SELECT work_address FROM test_workers WHERE work_cesid='". $data . "')";
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM geocoding WHERE address=". $condition);
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $arr = array();
    if($result){
      $arr[] = $result[0]['latitude'];
      $arr[] = $result[0]['longitude'];
   }
   return $arr;
```

}